# ASIHTTPRequest post json to php server

Tags: php, iphone, json, ios, asihttprequest

I have been trying to post a json object to a PHP script for the last 5 hours.  I have read all the docs and it seems the code should work BUT it does not.  The request is made and received ok, but I can't access the posted json data or dont even know if its been sent correctly.  I keep getting an empty php array, instead of the json data.

```
NSString *jsonString = [self.tableDataSource JSONRepresentation];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/test.php"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];


[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request appendPostData:[jsonString  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[request startSynchronous];
```

here is the php script (test.php)

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
print_r($decoded);
```

I am using the lastest ASIHttpRequest code from https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request.git

What am I doing wrong?????

Cheers,
Trav.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. I have no experience in iPhone development, but there *must* be monitoring tools that can show you  the success status, and response body of a request. On the PHP end, you can activate `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to output any possible problems.

Comment: Won't you need to access the $_POST[] variables?

Comment: Hi Pekka,  nothing is returned when i turn on error_reporting(E_ALL). Do you have more ideas?

Comment: Hi Les, I have tried print_r($_POST) and print_r($_GET); I still can't get any of the json data. anymore ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue.  I had a SSL redirect in the apache vhost config.  Used a tcp packet sniffer to find it.  once i remove the redirect i was able to receive the json data with:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
print_r($decoded);
```

Thanks to all those who helped.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that ASIHTTPRequest defaults to a GET request. YOu're trying to POST data so I don't think this will work.

Try using ASIFormDataRequest which is built for POSTing data. Or, at the very least change the request method to POST.

```
 [request  setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
```

Comment: Hi gnuchu,  have tried the setRequestMethod "POST" and ASIFormDataRequest and print_r($_POST) and print_r($_GET);  I still can't get any of the json data.  anymore idea?

Comment: I've not tried the setRequestMethod but I use the ASIFormDataRequest in a few apps and it works well. I can't diagnose if the issue is on the php side though as I don't know a huge amount about php.